# convergence of the series involving log function

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

I was asked about convergence of summation of $\log(n)/n^2$ and $\log(1+(1/n))/n^2$. I want to use only p series test. Is there any approximation for $\log(x)$?, Like sterling's approximation for factorials. Or is there any other method?

Comment: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(n)/n^{0.5} \rightarrow 0$ and $\ln(1+x) \sim x$ as $x \rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 1):

By p-series test,

$$\sum\frac{1}{n^{1.5}} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum\frac{1}{n^3} \quad \text{converge}$$

By the L'Hospital's rule, we have also have the following limits

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}}}{\frac{1}{n^{1.5}}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^{0.5}} = 0$$
and
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^3}}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$

By limit comparison test,

$$ \sum \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum\ \frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{n^2} \quad \text{converge}$$